# Complex query with if

Tags: c#, linq

I need to make a query like getUsers (list IDs);
I need to search by ids, if found then return users with ids in list, if not found then return all users, or if found only one return one user.

How can I write this query?

This is how I started:

```
 public List<User> getUsers (List<int> ids)        
 {
    using(var uow = _repository.CreateUnitOfWork())
    {               
        var u = uow.GetEntities<User>().Where(c => c.Id in ids);
        if (u == null) 
        u.ToList();                     
    }
}
```

Comment: and i need to use entity framework

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't make sense because the return type of a function must always be the same. It cannot return a `List` some of the time and a `User` the rest of the time.

I would suggest something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsersByIdOrAllUsers(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    using (var uow = _repository.CreateUnitOfWork())
    {
        var users = uow.GetEntities<User>();

        if (users.Any(c => ids.Contains(c.ID)))
        {
            return users.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ID));
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

You can then test if you only found one user:

```
var matchingUsers = GetUsersByIdOrAllUsers(ids);

if (matchingUsers.Any() && !matchingUsers.Skip(1).Any())
{
    var singleUser = matchingUsers.Single();

    // Do stuff with the single user...
}
```

Note that the use of `IEnumerable` makes operations lazy, and therefore more efficient. If you *really* want a `List`, just do:

```
var matchingUsersList = matchingUsers.ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `uow.GetEntities<User>()` returns `IQueryable<User>`, when there are users with ids from the list, the proposed solutions involve executing two expensive `IN (...)` SQL queries, also building and passing the `ids` list twice to the database - one for `Any` and one for `Where`.

I would rather structure it differently. I would execute a query with `Where` based on `ids.Contains` and materialize the result in memory. Then I would check locally if it contains data, and if yes, will return the result, otherwice will execute a second query **without** filter, which should be much more efficient.

Something like this:

```
public List<User> getUsers (List<int> ids)        
{
    using(var uow = _repository.CreateUnitOfWork())
    {               
        var allUsers = uow.GetEntities<User>();
        var matchingUsers = allUsers
            .Where(user => ids.Contains(user.Id))
            .ToList();
        return matchingUsers.Any() ? matchingUsers : allUsers.ToList();
    }
}
```

To recap, you cannot do what you want with a single database query. It requires executing at least two queries and the only question is to use the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way is to use `Join`

```
public List<User> getUsers (List<int> ids)        
 {
    using(var uow = _repository.CreateUnitOfWork())
    {               
        var u = uow.GetEntities<User>()
                      .Join(ids,x=>x.Id,y=>y,(x,y)=>x).ToList();
        if (u.Count==0) 
               return uow.GetEntities<User>().ToList()
         return u;           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a less chatty way to do it, but logically maybe something like this?:

```
if (uow.GetEntities<User>().Any(u => ids.Contains(u.ID))
    return uow.GetEntities<User>().Where(u => ids.Contains(u.ID)).ToList();
return uow.GetEntities<User>().ToList();
```

I'm assuming here that `uow.GetEntities<User>()` simply returns a queryable and doesn't itself materialize anything from the database or have any significant performance penalty.  If that's not the case, the code for this operation may need to be placed deeper in the DAL.

Comment: but this seems like you are executing the condition twice,

Comment: @Sherlock: The alternative as I see it is to always materialize the full list of users and check the condition in-memory, rather than check it twice against the data source.  That seems less ideal to me.  Between the two, checking the condition is probably less expensive than materializing unnecessary records.

Comment: But the second check is performed on the output of the first (and all the unnecessary records were filtered out), it is ideal also for me though

Comment: @Sherlock: It may depend on the data source, but an `Any()` should be a lot cheaper than a `Where()` and shouldn't actually be filtering/returning all records.  (`IF EXISTS` is pretty fast in T-SQL.)

Comment: what i mean is, execute the where condition first before checking `Any`. Sorry not a native english speaker. Same as what this guy answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/38787016/4827151

Comment: @Sherlock: Once the `Where()` condition is executed, there would be no need for the `Any()`.  However, in cases where the element is not found, that would be a more expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IList<User> getUsers (List<int > ids = null)
{                       
        var query = _repository.GetEntities<User>();

        if (ids == null)                
            return query.ToList();                  

        if (ids.Count()==1)
        {                    
             var singleUser = query.FirstOrDefault(user => ids.Contains(user.Id));
             if (singleUser!= null)                                     
                return new List<User>{ singleUser; };           

             return new List<User>();                
        }   

        return query.Where(user => ids.Contains(user.Id)).ToList();                                                     
}
```